# Trying to fire 3 projectiles at a time from multiple enemies but i keep running into this error and I don't know how to fix it

Tags: c#, visual-studio

The enemies are kept randomly spawned and I want each of them to fire at least 3 projectiles at the player each time but when i increase the MAX_PROJECTILES from 3+ it says my index is out of bounds of the array. Any help?

Using C# and microsoft visual studio. thanks!

here is my code :

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    RectangleF[] projectileHitBox = new RectangleF[MAX_PROJECTILES];
    SizeF projectileSize;
    PointF[] projectileLocation = new PointF[MAX_PROJECTILES];

    RectangleF playerHitBox;
    SizeF playerSize;
    PointF playerLocation;

    RectangleF[] enemyHitBox;
    SizeF enemySize;
    PointF[] enemyLocation;
    const int MAX_ENEMIES = 3;
    // Create a random number generator to randomly spawn enemies
    Random numberGenerator = new Random();

    // Used for variable speed and direction calculations
    const int MAX_PROJECTILES = 5;
    float[] projectileXSpeed = new float[MAX_PROJECTILES];
    float[] projectileYSpeed = new float[MAX_PROJECTILES];
    float[] baseLength = new float[MAX_PROJECTILES];
    float[] height = new float[MAX_PROJECTILES];
    float[] hypotenuse = new float[MAX_PROJECTILES];
    const float TOTAL_PROJECTILE_SPEED = 3;
    // only create a projectile when new one is needed
    bool[] createProjectile = new bool[MAX_PROJECTILES];
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        SetupProjectile();
        SetupEnemy();
        playerSetup();
    }
    // Moves a projectile; creates it if its not created
    void SetUpProjectileLocation()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < projectileHitBox.Length; i++)
        {
        // Only update the projectile if it a new one is needed
            if (createProjectile[i] == true)
            {
                createProjectile[i] = false;

                // calculate the base and height of the triangle from the enemy location to
                // the player location
                baseLength[i] = playerLocation.X - enemyLocation[i].X + i * 10;
                height[i] = playerLocation.Y - enemyLocation[i].Y;

                hypotenuse[i] = (float)Math.Sqrt((baseLength[i] * baseLength[i]) + (height[i] * height[i]));

                // projectile speed calculations along the x-axis are a fraction
                // of the total projectile's speed
                projectileXSpeed[i] = baseLength[i] / hypotenuse[i] * TOTAL_PROJECTILE_SPEED;
                projectileYSpeed[i] = height[i] / hypotenuse[i] * TOTAL_PROJECTILE_SPEED;

                projectileLocation[i] = new PointF(enemyLocation[i].X, enemyLocation[i].Y);
                projectileHitBox[i] = new RectangleF(projectileLocation[i], projectileSize);
            }
        }
    }
    // Move projectile according to the speeds calculated in setupprojectilelocation()
    void MoveProjectile()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < projectileLocation.Length; i++)
        {
            projectileLocation[i].X = projectileLocation[i].X + projectileXSpeed[i];
            projectileLocation[i].Y += projectileYSpeed[i];

            projectileHitBox[i].Location = projectileLocation[i];

            // if projectile hits player 
            if (projectileHitBox[i].IntersectsWith(playerHitBox))
            {
                createProjectile[i] = true;
                // do damage / kill
            }
            // If the projcetile goes off screen we need to create a new one
            else if (projectileLocation[i].X < 0 || projectileLocation[i].X > ClientSize.Width || projectileLocation[i].Y < 0 || projectileLocation[i].Y > ClientSize.Height)
            {
                createProjectile[i] = true;
            }
        }
    }
    // Projectile deafult size
    void SetupProjectile()
    {
        projectileSize = new SizeF(10, 10);

        // when game starts, all projectile needs to be created
        for (int i = 0; i < createProjectile.Length; i++)
        {
            createProjectile[i] = true;

        }
    }
    // player location
    void playerSetup()
    {
        playerLocation = new PointF(50, 50);
        playerSize = new SizeF(25, 25);
        playerHitBox = new RectangleF(playerLocation, playerSize);
    }
    void SetupEnemy()
    {
        enemyLocation = new PointF[MAX_ENEMIES];
        enemySize = new SizeF(25, 25);
        enemyHitBox = new RectangleF[MAX_ENEMIES];

        for (int i = 0; i < enemyHitBox.Length; i++)
        {
            enemyLocation[i] = new PointF(numberGenerator.Next(0, 400), numberGenerator.Next(0, 300));
            enemyHitBox[i] = new RectangleF(enemyLocation[i], enemySize);
        }

    }
    protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnPaint(e);
        for (int i = 0; i < enemyHitBox.Length; i++)
        {
            e.Graphics.FillRectangle(Brushes.Black, enemyHitBox[i]);
        }
        e.Graphics.FillRectangle(Brushes.Purple, playerHitBox);
        for (int i = 0; i < projectileHitBox.Length; i++)
        {
            e.Graphics.FillRectangle(Brushes.Pink, projectileHitBox[i]);

        }
    }
    private void tmrUpdate_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SetUpProjectileLocation();
        MoveProjectile();
        Refresh();
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you give us a clue which line the error is occurring?

Comment: @jdweng in baseLength[i] = playerLocation.X - enemyLocation[i].X + i * 10; 

it says the index was outside the bounds of the array

Comment: max enemies is only 3 : enemyLocation = new PointF[MAX_ENEMIES]; which is giving the out of bounds.  When you set MAX_PROJECTILES to 5 the enemies is still only 3 so i can be 3 or 4 so you get enemyLocation[3] and enemyLocation[4]